# Factoring Code C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I would like to know if it is possible to do a little refactoring with this code:

```
string code_region = "";
code_region = listeRegions.Single(x => x.nom == nvc[index + 1]).code_region; 
dt.code_region=code_region;
```

In this code nvc[index+1] value can be null or empty so i do not want my Linq query raising an exception...

I wonder if there is a way to do an inline LINQ query ? Should I use FirstOfDefault instead ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: This belongs on code review, you'll get a much better response there, unless the Jon Skeet comments directly below my comment.

Comment: Well what do you want to happen if there are no matches? And why are you assigning a value to `code_region` in the first line, only to reassign it? (I'd strongly advise you to revise your names to follow .NET naming conventions, btw.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yeah you're right with the variables names but this is only an example, i want to return empty value if there is no matches...

Comment: why don't you put an if condition?

Comment: Empty or null? A [mcve] would make it much clearer... and I would advise you to follow conventions even in example code... after all, you want to make it as simple and familiar for readers as possible, right?

Comment: Why does it matter that `nvc[index+1]` can be null? You're not returning that, you're returning whatever is matched from `listeRegions`.

Comment: I beg your pardon guys, here is few more explanations:


listeRegions.Single(x => x.nom == nvc[index + 1]).code_region => Can return null OR empty since we don't know if nvc[index+1] contains a value or not

So i was wondering if there was a way to test if the value is null within the LINQ query and then return empty value in this case (returning empty is fine)

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: @Jeff The query can *only* return null if it finds a match and that has null for `code_region`. In all other cases you'll either get an exception for no match and an exception if your index is out of range.  Which of the three are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks for your answer, i'm trying to avoid the second case you mentionned :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, you seem sure that the index is in range, so you're only looking to resolve the exception that will occur when you don't find a match.

`SingleOrDefault` will return the default (null, in this case), so you could use this, check for null, and return `code_region` in the case you have a result.

However, you can avoid the check by not 'leaving the monad' until the end.  Use `Where` and `Select` to filter by your condition and choose the item's `code_region` and then call `SingleOrDefault` on that. This way you'll get the matched items `code_region`, or you'll get null when there's no item matching your criteria.

```
 var code_region = listeRegions
    .Where(x => x.nom == nvc[index + 1])
    .Select(x => x.code_region)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

My two grains of sand:

```
// Convert to string to let it work against an SQL database
var nvcStr =  nvc[index + 1];

// Avoid exception if no match - FirstOrDefault
var code_region_obj = listeRegions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nom == nvcStr); 
dt.code_region=code_region_obj == null?string.empty:code_region_obj.code_region;
```

Comment: Thanks @jorge that's it !! Final syntax for the third line is: dt.code_region = code_region_obj == null ? string.Empty : code_region_obj.code_region;

Comment: Yes, a typo :) I will correct it!